# GraphQL and springboot resolver mapping problem

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I have created my schema and my resolver class and i implement GraphQLQueryResolver but it is not mapping it[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MxRr.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5sGX.jpg)

I tried injecting some dependancies like java kickstart for graphql, and i annotated the method in my resolver class with @QueryMapping and still not working, when i test everything in my graphiql interface it is returning null for me